# American English Corpus with spoken language exchange

Tags: corpora, resource-request

I'm looking for an American English Corpus with spoken language exchange. There are many terms used. E.g. eTandem, tandem, etc. 
TIA

Comment: What do you mean by spoken language exchange? Are you just after a corpus of dialogue?

Comment: No I'm interested in language exchange where one learner teaches the other and vice versa.

Comment: [MICASE](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/micase/) might have something for you, then.

Comment: Hi Is there an intro to using MICASE you would recommend? Would ANTCONC be an option? This one seems easy to use from the videos on YouTube.

Answer (score 2):

As jlawyer states [Micase](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/micase/) might have something useful for you. It contains some language tutorials. You certainly could use ANTCONC with Micase, it really depends exactly what you want to investigate. It might be worth considering annotating relevant excerpts with a general annotation tool such as Amber Stubbs's [MAE](https://code.google.com/p/mae-annotation/).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and direction. I appreciate it. I'm in Taiwan and sometimes its difficult to find people to bounce ideas off. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

[A Survey of Available Corpora For Building Data-Driven Dialogue Systems](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.05742) ([PDF](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.05742v2.pdf)), recently published by researchers at the Université de Montréal and McGill, has a good overview.

[image]

The relevant section *Human-Human Spoken Corpora* gives overviews and links to:
- Switchboard dataset
- British National Corpus
- CALLHOME American English Speech Corpus
- CALLFRIEND American English-Non-Southern Dialect Corpus
- Bergen Corpus of London Teenager Language
- Longman Spoken American Corpus
...

I won't list them all here.

Further down you will find *Constrained Spoken Corpora* (domain-specific) and *Scripted Spoken Corpora* (films).

Answer (score 0):

You can see [The Open American National Corpus](http://www.anc.org/) with free online n-grams search engine or download.