# Freely available corpus of recorded dialogues

Tags: resource-request, dialog-acts

Is there a freely available and downloadable corpus recorded English language dialogues available?

Ideally such a corpus would include transcripts and time-markers for each speaker.

I have found this list: http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.05742. However none of the options are available for download.

Comment: Really free resources of this kind are rare, can you be more specific on your requirements, e.g., is a non-commercial restriction or "free for academic research" good enough for you?

Comment: See also: [American English Corpus with spoken language exchange](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/14926/american-english-corpus-with-spoken-language-exchange/14956)

Comment: You can also try http://opendata.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Yes, non-commercial or free-for-academic research are fine.

Answer (score 2):

Concretely I would suggest film subtitles or telephone data, depending on your exact application.

[A Survey of Available Corpora For Building Data-Driven Dialogue Systems](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.05742) ([PDF](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.05742v2.pdf)), published by researchers at the Université de Montréal and McGill, has a good overview.

[image]

The relevant section *Human-Human Spoken Corpora* gives overviews and links to:
- Switchboard dataset
- British National Corpus
...

Further down you will find *Constrained Spoken Corpora* (domain-specific) and *Scripted Spoken Corpora* (films).  [opensubtitles.org](http://opensubtitles.org) is also widely used.